# String Concatenation in C with Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

So this is the standard string concatenation code in C:

```
char *stringcat(char *dest, const char *src){
    char *save=dest;
    while(*save !='\0'){
        save++;
    }
    while(*src!='\0'){
        *save=*src;
        save++;
        src++;
    }
    *save='\0';
    return dest;
}
```

My question is why when we replace the first while loop with the following:

```
while(*save++){};
```

It does not work, but, when replaced with:

```
while(*++save){};
```

It does work.  In the first two instances, save points to the null terminator at the end of dest at the end, which is then overwritten by the first character in src.  However, in the third instance, it seems like save will be pointing to the character **after** the null terminator, which is weird.

Comment: How / why do you think they should be same?

Comment: Hmmm,  Try `char buf[10] = "123"; stringcat(buf, &buf[1]); puts(buf);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make it `while (*save++) {}`, the operation you are repeating is: load byte, increment pointer, check whether byte was zero. Therefore, what will happen at the end of the string is: load null byte, increment pointer, check whether byte was zero, see it was, exit loop. So `save` will be pointing just after the null byte. But you want to start copying the second string *on top* of that null byte, not after it.

(Is it possible that you have the meanings of `++save` and `save++` interchanged in your head? If so, here's a useful mnemonic: `++save` means increment, then load the value; `save++` means load the value, then increment. So the order in which the variable name and the `++` appear corresponds to the order of operations.)

Comment: Yeah I think I had the idea of the two of them switched.  When I run
    `char a[10]="hello"; char b[10]="goodbye"; stringcat(a,b); puts(a);`
Then, a will contain: `"hello\0goodbye"`, which will print out "hello" through puts, right?  On the other hand, through using ++save I gurantee that save will point to the null terminator at the end, to overwrite it?

Comment: Right. I want to point out one other thing, though. `"hello\0goodbye\0"` (don't forget the final null character!) is 14 characters, so now you've written past the end of array `a` and all sorts of bad things could happen. This is called a "buffer overflow", it's a *really common* kind of error, and any time you're working with arrays and pointers in C you should be keeping it in mind and making sure it doesn't happen. It's a real pain and easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(*save++)
```

First dereference save and compare that value to 0, then increment save.

```
while(*save !='\0'){
    save++;
}
```

First dereference save, compare to 0 and only increment if non-zero.
See the difference?